# Multiple VMs acting as web servers using KVM where only 1 external IP is available

Tags: ssh, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to set up a server for my lab, on which we will run multiple web services and sites. Since there will be a few people setting up and administering those services, I decided (after lots of googling/reading) that the best way in order to avoid conflicts etc is to create a series of VMs. I have dealt a little with VMs before, but for much simpler scenarios.

The host OS is CentOS 7 and the KVM guests I already setup are using debian. I initially used bridged interface but, obviously, this was a wrong choice since I have **only one external IP available**. So, I think, what I need to do is create an internal LAN that connects the host with the guests, as shown in this diagram I made (still, the **admins should be able to access, through ssh, each VM** from outside.):

[image: Host - VMs diagram]

My question is this:

How would I go about **creating an "internal LAN" where each VM can still be accessible from outside using SSH without using a bridged interface** (which would be easy but not feasible in my case)?

Comment: You should consider to use a traditional shared webhosting approach instead of multiple VMs.

Comment: Thanks for still partially answering one of the questions. I just edited my questions. Would you happen to know any resources about implementing shared webhosting in a single machine? Everything I found was about shared webhosting providers.

Comment: Essentially, you would become a small webhosting provider!

Comment: Actually, if you knew me, you would know that I am anything but small :).

Thanks for the input, I will look into it.

Comment: Why do you try to avoid bridging?

Answer (score 0):

If question about ssh access to VMs in such configuration.

You have a different choises (ordered not best-first):

- On KVM host Dst-nat different tcp ports to different VM.
- Use dedicated VM as SSH "proxy" by creating ssh tunnel or nested ssh.
- Use VPN to Internal LAN, using dedicated VM as VPN server and dst-nat vpn port on KVM (secure) or using KVM as VPN server (simple)

If You think about web access:

- use dedicated VM as reverse-proxy

**PS.**
I understand whu put different sites on different VMs rather on one shared.
 - Security (compromising one site less probably touch others)
 - Requirements (different sites can require different versions or even different OS)

**Added:**

I look at question from other perspective - network design.

Only ways achieve Your goal in question (make ssh on VM directly accessible for admins):

- Assign externally routable IPs to VM.

  - If "external IP" is Public Internet Adress - public IPs and ensure it routable in Internet.
  - If "external IP" is private - private IPs and make it routable over all Your LAN

Comment: The question is mostly about how I would go about setting the network, keeping in mind that I have to setup ssh. But you input is useful to me. You 1st solution seems more suitable since I would rather avoid the additional overhead of another VM

Comment: I tried to improve my answer. But Im in doubts, what about "setting network" You want to know.